# Is it possible to express kotlin 'with' method equivalent in Scala?

Tags: scala, kotlin, higher-order-functions

Kotlin Standard lib contains the ['with' method](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L43) that receives an object and a method of that object defined as:

```
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R = receiver.block()
```

And can be used as:

```
val str = "string"
with(str) {
  println(size)) // will print 6; equals to "string".size
  println(substring(3)) // will print (ing); equals to "string".substring(3)
}
```

How to define similar method in Scala?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way to define such a method in Scala, because the concept of [function literals with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) does not exist in Scala.

However, Scala's `import` is general enough that you can use it *instead* of `with`. Your example would write as:

```scala
val str = "string"
import str._
println(length)
println(substring(3))
```

Note that `size` specifically does not work with this scheme because it happens to be implicitly pimped on `String`, so I had to use `length` instead. However, in general, this is the pattern we use.

Edit after comment: if you want to explicitly *scope* the import to a portion of your code, you can do so with braces, which are always allowed to scope things:

```scala
val str = "string"

{
  import str._
  println(length)
  println(substring(3))
}
println(length) // does not compile
```

Note that the blank line is necessary, otherwise it will be parsed as trying to call the `apply` method on `"string"` with the `{...}` as argument. To avoid this problem, you can use the `locally` method:

```scala
val str = "string"
locally {
  import str._
  println(length)
  println(substring(3))
}
println(length) // does not compile
```

`locally` per se doesn't do anything; it is only used to visually highlight that the braces are there only for scoping reasons, and by extension to help parsing do the right thing.

Comment: The main difference I can see is that the kotlin with has limited scope, while scala import scope is not that limited. Nevertheless it seems the best possible in scala yes :)

Comment: @pedrorijo91 I have updated my answer to address that.

Comment: `val str = "hello" : { def size: Int }` almost works but then `size` does not warn about reflective access. (I was hoping we could avoid reflection without knowing the name of the conversion or the wrapper.)